# Creating workbooks named based on a data from a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Here is what I want to do: I have a data in "Report" tab. Column A contains ID1, column B ID2 and the rest is other data. I would like to to have a macro which takes all row data for given ID2 and creates a workbook named in a specific format (name contains that ID2). It could be saved in the same folder as macro or ask user to specify location.

As for now I've tried to reconstruct a macro which does something similar: it creates tabs instead of workbooks and I have a problem changing filter from column A to column B.

```
Sub PagesByDescription()
Dim rRange As Range, rCell As Range
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet
Dim strText As String

Set wSheetStart = ActiveSheet
wSheetStart.AutoFilterMode = False
'Set a range variable to the correct item column
Set rRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

    'Delete any sheet called "UniqueList"
    'Turn off run time errors & delete alert
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("UniqueList").Delete

    'Add a sheet called "UniqueList"
    Worksheets.Add().Name = "UniqueList"

       'Filter the Set range so only a unique list is created
        With Worksheets("UniqueList")
            rRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , _
             Worksheets("UniqueList").Range("a1"), True

             'Set a range variable to the unique list, less the heading.
             Set rRange = .Range("a1", .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        With wSheetStart
            For Each rCell In rRange
              strText = rCell
             .Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, strText
                Worksheets(strText).Delete
                'Add a sheet named as content of rCell
                Worksheets.Add().Name = strText
                'Copy the visible filtered range _
                (default of Copy Method) and leave hidden rows
                .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
                ActiveSheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
            Next rCell
        End With

    With wSheetStart
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Activate
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Could anyone give me a hint? Changing A1 to B1 in the code doesn't work..

Thanks everyone in advance!

=========================================

**Update**: I've added a loop but It doesn't seem to be done right.

```
Sub PagesByDescription()
Dim rRange As Range, rCell As Range
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet
Dim strText As String
dim i as integer

Set wSheetStart = ActiveSheet
wSheetStart.AutoFilterMode = False
'Set a range variable to the correct item column
Set rRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

    'Delete any sheet called "UniqueList"
    'Turn off run time errors & delete alert
    'On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ' Worksheets("UniqueList").Delete

    'Add a sheet called "UniqueList"
  '  Worksheets.Add().Name = "UniqueList"


    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "UniqueList"

       'Filter the Set range so only a unique list is created
        With Sheets("UniqueList")
            rRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , _
             Worksheets("UniqueList").Range("a1"), True

             'Set a range variable to the unique list, less the heading.
             Set rRange = .Range("a1", .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
        End With

        'On Error Resume Next
        With wSheetStart
            For Each rCell In rRange
              strText = rCell
              for i = 1 to 2
             .Range("1:1").AutoFilter i, strText
              next i
                'Worksheets(strText).Delete
                'Add a sheet named as content of rCell
                'Worksheets.Add().Name = strText
                Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = strText
                'Copy the visible filtered range _
                (default of Copy Method) and leave hidden rows
                .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
                ActiveSheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
            Next rCell
        End With

    With wSheetStart
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Activate
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

It still uses column A for filter, now doesn't even copy anything, just creating tabs named by Unique list.

Comment: You need to change the `Field` parameter of autofilter from `1` to `2` (see [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel)). • Remove **all** `On Error Resume Next` lines from your code. This line just hides **all** error messages in the entire procedure, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. This line does not fix any errors! It just makes you blind and you cannot debug your code anymore.

Comment: Hello, thanks for advise! It hasn't solved it though. I've updated the code to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please use for next loop on filter to move from 1 to 2. You can add second line also with new filter if you want use both filter.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer blow example:-

Sub etst()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 2

```
Range("1:1").AutoFilter i, ">" & 1200
```

Next i

End Sub

Comment: Please post only one answer (there is a edit button), so you can combine them. And format your code nicely as code block. On any questions about that the [help] might be useful.

Comment: Hi Shyam! Thanks for the advise. I've updated my code above, I still must do something wrong.. It uses column A for filter and doesn't copy anything.